# How to change color in lwjgl texture

Tags: java, colors, bitmap, textures, lwjgl

I have the following texture: [image: lwjgl texture width 128, height 32]

The black pixels are characters, the background is transparent.
How do I change the black pixels of the characters to another color?
I use this texture as a bitmap for tekst rendering in lwjgl. Is there a way to change the black pixels to red?
I would appreciate an example.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware glColor* also applies for textures. If you change the black color of your font to white the given color would simply apply to this.